# Looping issues in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to get information from a data table .txt file from a list of objects in another .txt file.
in the code List.txt looks like

```
Obj2
Obj5
Obj6
etc.
```

and DataTable.txt looks something like

```
Obj1    Data1
Obj2    Data2
Obj3    Data3
etc.
```

I tried

```
f = file('List.txt')
g = file('DataTable.txt')

for line in f:
    l = line.split()
    name = l[0]
    for row in g:
        if row.startswith(name):
            data = row.split()
            print data[8]
```

but it only prints the data for the first entry on the list.  Can anyone find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the fine answers given by @Borealid and @Ignacio,

```
f = file('List.txt')
g = file('DataTable.txt')

for line in f:
    l = line.split()
    name = l[0]
    g.seek(0)
    for row in g:
        if row.startswith(name):
            data = row.split()
            print data[8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a `file` consumes it. Either seek back to the beginning, or cache one of the files in a sequence.

Comment: Specifically, doing: `buf = g.readlines()` and then replacing `for row in g` with `for row in buf` will probably do what you expect, as long as it's comfortable to hold DataTable in memory. (Also, if you have a big data set you can hold in memory you will query repeatedly, it is probably faster to read DataTable into a dictionary and query the dictionary rather than to do a search through a DataTable list every time you want to access a value.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you went all the way through `g` on the first line of `f`. On the second line of `f`, `g` has nothing more to give.

You need to reset `g` back to its first line. You can do this by putting `start_pos = g.tell()` just after `g.open`, then a `g.seek(start_pos)` after the `for row in g` has completed.

Answer (score 0):

As you iterate over a file, you move the position that you're reading from. Think of it as a cursor moving through the file. In order to bypass this issue, simply read in the data before-hand and iterate over that.

```
f = file('List.txt').read().splitlines()       #read in the whole file, then split on the lines
g = file('DataTable.txt').read().splitlines()  #read in the whole file, then split on the lines

for line in f:
    l = line.split()
    name = l[0]
    for row in g:
        if row.startswith(name):
            data = row.split()
            print data[8]
```